# Can't boot GRUB2, boot doesn't anything

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

I messed up my UEFI boot. I used to have an ubuntu partition and a windows partition, booting from the efi partition.

But now I can't seem to boot on anything. I removed my windows partition via live ubuntu and gparted (and resized it).

I also ran boot-repair tool and followed the [gparted FAQ](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem).

You can find the [boot-repair report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pTMykWfCCh/).

The boot repair detects the grub2 partition and the ubuntu partition, but if I boot my system, I have nothing in the boot options... the hard drive is correctly detected.

What should I do?

I could just remove everything and re-install but I would much prefer not to have to re-install everything on my machine :(

Comment: Grub on gpt partitioned drives can boot in either UEFI mode using ESP - efi system partition  (FAT32) or in BIOS mode using a tiny 1 or 2 MB bios_grub partition. It looks like you converted UEFI boot Ubuntu to BIOS boot with a huge bios_grub. The bios_grub probably was the ESP?? I would convert your sda1 back to an ESP, by formatting to FAT32 with boot flag with gparted. Then in Boot-Repair's advanced options do a total reinstall of grub to get UEFI version of grub. Be sure to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode to run Boot-Repair in UEFI mode.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks XXXX times! Create an answer for me to accept ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grub on gpt partitioned drives can boot in either UEFI mode using ESP - efi system partition (FAT32) or in BIOS mode using a tiny 1 or 2 MB bios_grub partition.

It looks like you converted UEFI boot Ubuntu to BIOS boot with a huge bios_grub. The bios_grub probably was the ESP?? I would convert your sda1 back to an ESP, by formatting to FAT32 with boot flag with gparted. Either use version in Ubuntu live installer or a gparted live ISO version.

https://gparted.sourceforge.io/index.php

Then in Boot-Repair's advanced options do a total reinstall of grub to get UEFI version of grub. Be sure to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode to run Boot-Repair in UEFI mode.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Not sure if you recover the ESP, it it will have the Windows UEFI boot entry. If totally new partition it will not. Grub only boots working Windows and looks for the Windows ESP entry to boot from. But if Windows turns fast start back on, grub will not boot it and you must boot from UEFI boot entry to turn fast start off, or make other repairs. You can add a Windows entry by running repairs from your Windows repair disk or use efibootmgr in Ubuntu. See IV and restore Windows entry:

[Dual boot Win 8 / Ubuntu loads only Win](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789)